# How to point another website using Bootstrap tabs?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, tabs, href

I have tried the following code,

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="nav-item" id="web1Tab"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" id="w1" href="link_to_website_1">Website1</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" id="web2Tab"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="w2" href="link_to_website_2">Website2</a></li>
</ul>
```

It did look just like as I expected, however `href` doesn't work. On the other hand, if I remove the `data-toggle="tab"` part then `href`'s work properly but `active` tab doesn't change. I guess that, `href` in this case only supports inner linking? I am not sure. The code looks very simple but I was unable solve it.

Comment: If you want to navigate to another website, why do you care about whether a tab is active or not?

Comment: Also ,Bootstrap tabs are used to switch with the content of the current page and cannot be used for page jumps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try surrounding your entire list item with a href?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <a style="display:block" href="your_url1_here">
    <li class="nav-item" id="web1Tab">Website1</li>
  </a>

  <a style="display:block" href="your_url2_here">
    <li class="nav-item" id="web2Tab">Website2</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not valid HTML. `a` tags are not permitted as direct content of `ul` elements.

Comment: According to my testing, it's okay (the console did not raise anything) to put the `a` tag outside the `li` item. Otherwise, if you put the `a` block inside the `li` class, the `href` property will only apply to the text `WebsiteX`

Comment: It might be okay, and browsers may act as you would want them to, but this is still invalid according to the HTML specification, so this might not work in all browsers and may stop working at any time.

Comment: @poke then are there any ways to do this? I've tried searching for other methods but either they won't work (even in Windows) or they are only applied to the text

Comment: Usually, you would just make the links within your list items `display: block`. That way, they occupy the whole element. Any style then gets added to the link instead of the list item. So the list item only becomes a transparent container for the link.